# How To Render ChoiceField options in Django template

Tags: python, django

I am trying to render a ChoiceField in django template, I do not know if i am doing the right thing but the selected ChoiceField saved in database when form is submitted. Now, how do i get the selected choice(Like Placeholder). If choice field is empty i do not want to see (---) I want a placeholder (Choose your gender). And when a gender is selected, i want the placeholder to be replaced by the value(Male instead of Choose your gender).

[image]

[image]

Views.py:

```
def profile_edit(request):
    updateform = UpdateUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
    profileeditform = ProfileEditForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if updateform.is_valid() and profileeditform.is_valid(): 
            updateform.save()
            profileeditform.save()
            messages.info(request, 'Your profile was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('site:profile-edit')
        else:
            updateform = UpdateUserForm(instance=request.user)
            profileeditform = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    
    #I am trying to get the value of gender choices field of user and pass it value to template, but i am getting an error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'male'"
    gender = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user.profile.gender)

context = {
    'updateform': updateform,
    'profileeditform': profileeditform,
    'gender': gender,
}
return render(...)
```

Model.py:

```
GENDER = (
('male', 'male'),
('female', 'female'),
('custom', 'custom'),
('Prefer Not To Say', 'Prefer Not To Say'),
)

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True) 
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=GENDER, verbose_name="gender", blank=True)
```

Forms.py:

```
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'bio',
            'phone',
            'gender',
        )
```

Template.html:

```
<select class="custom-select md-form" name="gender" id="id_gender">
{% for male,female in profileeditform.fields.gender.choices %}
   <option value="{{ male }}" {% if profileeditform.fields.gender.value == male %} selected=""{% endif %}>{{ female }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last paragraph of the documentation on [model field choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) explains how to achieve this:

> ..add a tuple to choices containing None; e.g. (None, 'Your String For Display').

So in your models.py:

```py
GENDER = (
(None, 'Choose your gender'),
('male', 'male'),
('female', 'female'),
('custom', 'custom'),
('Prefer Not To Say', 'Prefer Not To Say'),
)
```

You will probably need to change your views.py, because you were [binding the forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#bound-and-unbound-forms) before checking if the `request.method` was 'POST'. The following follows the logic [recommended in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#the-view):

```py
def profile_edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        updateform = UpdateUserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profileeditform = ProfileEditForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if updateform.is_valid() and profileeditform.is_valid(): 
            updateform.save()
            profileeditform.save()
            messages.info(request, 'Your profile was successfully updated!')
            return redirect('site:profile-edit')
    else:
        updateform = UpdateUserForm(instance=request.user)
        profileeditform = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'updateform': updateform,
        'profileeditform': profileeditform,
        'gender': gender,
    }
    return render(...)
```

Update your forms.py and nominate the widget (this is necessary if you want to set class names, etc):

```py
class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'bio',
            'phone',
            'gender',
        )
        widgets = {
            'gender': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'custom-select md-form'}),
        }
```

Then you should be able to just render the form field in your template:

```html
{{ profileeditform.gender }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I missed that part. It worked. But how do i replace Choose a gender to Male if Male is selected?

Comment: I've updated the answer. If you allow the modelform field to render, it should work as you need.

Comment: I am not getting the selected value. I mean when I select Male and form is submitted, I want Male to replace Choose your gender in form.

Comment: I've updated the answer again. Use the views.py code and see how you go.

Comment: The form submits and save value in database, what I want is how I can show the value selected by user in the form by replacing (choose your gender to Male, if user select Male in choice field and save in database). When I select Male in choice field, I still see (choose your gender, instead of male). I tried your answer by placing form under request.method and I got error "update form references before assignment"

Comment: I have updated my question by attaching an image for clarification. When a user select Male and submit form, I want the value male to be shown in form like a placeholder, not choose your gender.

Comment: What you have described is exactly how django ModelForms are designed to operate. The error you mentioned will be because you missed some of the changes I've made to the `profile_edit` view. Copy the whole example I provided, fill in the `return render(...)` section with whatever you've already got, and that should work.

Comment: I have gotten what I wanted, I just posted my answer. I have learnt something new in your own answer... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to solve this problem:

Note: Do not include (None, 'Choose your gender') in choices field, it will override the selected value not to show in form.

```
<select class="custom-select md-form" name="gender" id="id_gender">
#I added this new line to template, it shows the selected gender of a user in form when form is submitted.
<option value="{{ user.profile.gender }}">{{ user.profile.gender }}</option>

{% for male,female in profileeditform.fields.gender.choices %}
<option value="{{ male }}" {% if profileeditform.fields.gender.value == male %} selected=""{% endif %}>{{ female }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```